# Append docker run command switches to docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, qnap

My QNAP NAS has the ability to run Docker containers.  But the UI is limited.  You can't change the `docker run` command invocation.

You can however use 'advaned' mode and use `docker-compose` and a YAML file instead.

I need to somehow pass an additional `--sig-proxy=false` to the invocation of `docker run` or in the case of using YAML, `docker-compose up`.

Is there a way to add docker switches to the YAML file as though they were on the command line?

Comment: Most Docker settings have [Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) equivalents; if it's an option after the `docker run image-name`, that gets passed in as the container `command:`.  Is there something more specific you're trying to configure?  Are you writing your own application, or just running prebuilt containers in this environment?

Comment: Its as simple as stated.  Specifically a 'bug' in Apache means SIGWINCH makes it quit.  That signal is generated by shells when the window changes size.  The Docker console in QNAP changes size as soon as you start it. So opening a console kills the container :(  the fix is --sig-proxy=false.  But you can't change docker command lines, its all menu driven.

Comment: I already looked through docker-compose manual and could not find a YAML key that does what I need, but the manual is rather disjointed, hence my question.